# How much of a bad idea is it to allow users to send arbitrary emails via our servers

Tags: email, security, server

My company is developing a cloud contact management service and on our iOS app we're having some problems launching a particular enterprise email client app when the user presses the "Email" button on one of their contacts.

One member of our team came up with an idea to get around the problems with this enterprise app:
We let the user specify their email address in the app's settings and create our own email composing screen. Tapping the email button on a contact would open the composing screen, they would write their message and then we would send it on their behalf from our servers (or via service like mailchimp).

Basically, this would mean we would have to create an endpoint on our api that would accept a POST request with 'from', 'to', 'subject', and 'body' fields which would send the appropriate email.

This seems like a very bad idea as it's essentially creating a free, anonymous email service that could easily be abused send spam.

A few extra notes about our setup:

- We don't verify an accounts email when they sign up
- Even if we did verify the account's email, the user would need to be able to specify any email, as they may have signed up with personal email, but want to email someone from their work email.
- Our API doesn't currently have any kind of rate limiting
- Instead of having a from field in the request, we could instead send the id of the contact they want to email. This doesn't really change anything because if someone wants to abuse the send email endpoint they can also abuse the create contact endpoint.

So exactly how much of a bad idea is this, and how can I convince my team not to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few thoughts against doing it:

- This is the perfect spamming service, which could damage the reputation of your company (reputational risk).
- Your email servers would very quickly make it into blacklists (RBLs), making your outgoing emails land in spam folders in very many recipients' mailboxes.
- Even if your servers are not yet in RBLs, if you send a forged email like that and proper email security is set up at the recipient end, your emails will still have a good chance to get classified as spam. Have a look at [things](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582267-About-SPF-and-DKIM) like [SPF](http://kb.kerio.com/product/kerio-connect/server-configuration/antispam/how-do-i-create-an-spf-or-caller-id-record-248.html) and [DKIM](http://dkim.org/).
- This could even have legal implications. Imagine the scenario when one of your users uses this service for something like blackmail. Would you be able to prove it was not you? Probably yes with the right controls, but would you want the hassle?
- Still on the legal side, many countries (the EU, mainly) have data protection regulations which strictly control how personal data like email addresses can be used, especially for commercial advertisement. You probably want to adhere to that, but that would be hard with such a service (note that I'm not a lawyer, in such a case it's probably the abuser of your service that would offend these regulations and not you, I don't know, but it's something to consider).
- If anyone can just send emails, it will be fairly easy to perform a denial of service attack against your services.

A few controls you could implement to mitigate some risks:

- When adding a sender (from) address, you should validate that by for example sending a (cryptographically random) token and checking if the user can send it back (eg. by clicking a link in the email). If he can, that proves to some extent that he controls the email address and is probably a valid sender.
- Limit the possible recipient addresses if you can. The best would be if recipients had to opt in to receive emails. If this is not possible, at least let recipients opt out from further emails. For this, you would have to add something like a footer to emails with "never again" links, and implement a facility to maintain recipients to which you must not send anymore.
- Implement rate limiting. Depending on your exact scenario and use case, only allow to send the least number of emails acceptable for your application.
- Implement proper logging so that you have an audit log of who exactly sent what email to whom. For this, log metadata like IP addresses as well. For this, you will likely have to authenticate your users.
- On an operational level, have monitoring in place, and be prepared to ban offending users, based on a clear ToS shared with your users.